# i want it to be exactly aligned inside the apartment

Tags: html, css

I did something like this for the level system. But I think I did something wrong because of my carelessness. As an example, I showed the number 10, but this number is 1-2-3, etc. it breaks down when we do. Can you help please

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(40deg, #ffffff, #0c8a86 50%, #ffffff);
  animation: rotate 12s linear infinite;
  display: inline-grid;
  top: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(#1c1734, #534770);
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.box:before {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff, #ffffff 40%, #ffffff);
  filter: blur(8px);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /*filter: hue-rotate(360deg);*/
  }
}

.circle-num {
  color: white!important;
  position: relative;
  place-self: center!important;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 25px!important;
  top: 17.51px;
  left: 21.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="circle-num">10</div>
```

i know I shouldn't do it with the position, but how would the solution to this be?

Answer (score 0):

Set a container with relative to contain the elements inside so that you can set an absolute positioned element (for the numbering).

With a fixed width and height of 50px and some calculation on any existing margin/padding you can easily position your number with flex and align it vertical and horizontally centered with align-items and justify-content.

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(40deg, #ffffff, #0c8a86 50%, #ffffff);
    animation: rotate 12s linear infinite;
    display: inline-grid;
    top: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    inset: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(#1c1734, #534770);
    border-radius: inherit;
}

.box:before {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff, #ffffff 40%, #ffffff);
    filter: blur(8px);
}

@keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        /*filter: hue-rotate(360deg);*/
    }
}

.circle-num {
    color: white !important;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 25px !important;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px 10px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="circle-num">1</div>
</div>
```